# div inside a div is not accepting any input + html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a vertical navigation bar on my website. When I click on a link in the navigation bar the content is shown in the content div. My problem is that content that is shown in the content div is a form and it is not accepting any input. Help me out

```js
/*right click disable*/
/*$(function() {
  $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});*/

$('.nav1', this).hide();


//drop down -logout
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".account").click(function() {
    var X = $(this).attr('id');
    if (X == 1) {
      $(".submenu").hide();
      $(this).attr('id', '0');
    } else {
      $(".submenu").show();
      $(this).attr('id', '1');
    }
  });

  //Mouse click on sub menu
  $(".submenu").mouseup(function() {
    return false
  });

  //Mouse click on my account link
  $(".account").mouseup(function() {
    return false
  });

  //Document Click
  $(document).mouseup(function() {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(".account").attr('id', '');
  });
});


/* drop down for sidebar*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#kl").click(function() {
    $("#kll").toggle();
  });
});


/* show div */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    var divname = this.name;
    $("#" + divname).show().siblings().hide();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
/*http://jsfiddle.net/EnKwU/4/*/

.nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 85%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 12px 50px 40px 100px;
  float: left;
}
.nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
.nav ul {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  margin-right: -80px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
.nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #339966;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #1bbc9b;
}
.nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.3em 0.8em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #444;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav ul ul {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}
.nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 0.4em 1.2em;
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.nav ul ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.nav1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  top: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 26%;
  top: 220px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  z-index: -100;
}
/*http://www.9lessons.info/2012/06/simple-drop-down-menu-with-jquery-and.html*/

.dropdown {
  color: #555;
  margin: 3px -22px 0 0;
  width: 143px;
  position: relative;
  height: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
}
.submenu {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 135px;
  display: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 40px 0 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  clear: both;
}
.dropdown li a {
  color: #555555;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown li a:hover {
  background: #155FB0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.account {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #555;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 110;
  display: block;
  padding: 11px 0 0 20px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 121px;
  margin: -11px 0 0 -10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: url(icons/arrow.png) 116px 17px no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.root {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 11px 0 0 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
}
/*  http://codepen.io/daniesy/pen/pfxFi 
icons :  http://fontawesome.io/

*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.fa {
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 22px !important;
}
.nav1 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 50px;
}
.nav1 label {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  background: #ECF0F1;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
.nav1 ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  background: #ECF0F1;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}
.nav1 label:hover {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav1 ul li:hover {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav1 label {
  color: #1ABC9C;
  border-left: 4px solid #1ABC9C;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.nav1 input {
  display: none;
}
.nav1 input ~ ul {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.nav1 input:checked + label {
  background: #1ABC9C;
  color: white;
}
.nav1 input:checked ~ ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}
.nav1 ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: 4px solid #E74C3C;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(1) .fa {
  color: #E74C3C;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(1):hover {
  background: #E74C3C;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 4px solid #0072B5;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(2) .fa {
  color: #0072B5;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: #0072B5;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(3) {
  border-left: 4px solid #EC1559;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(3) .fa {
  color: #EC1559;
}
.nav1 ul li:nth-child(3):hover {
  background: #EC1559;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#container {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-family: raleway z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---header and side bar for user name and logout menu -starts here -->
<div class = "nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Active Directory</a>
        <li><a href="#">HelpDesk</a>
        <li><a href="#">CTS</a>
        <li><a href="#">Exchange/Infra</a>
        <li><a href="#">Others</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact US</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--horizantal navigation bar ends here -->

<!---vetical navigation bar starts here-->
<div class="nav1">
  <label for="toggle2" id="kl">Active Directory</label>
  <ul class="animate" style="display:none" id="kll">
    <li class="animate"><a href="#" name="div1">Create Domain User</a></li>
    <li class="animate"><a href="#" name="div2">Domain Password Reset</a></li>
    <li class="animate"><a href="#" name="div3">Domain Joining</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!---vetical navigation bar ends here-->

<div class="content">
  <div id="div1" style="display:none">
    <!---->
    <div id="AD-FORM">
      <h2>AD-FORM</h2>
      <form name="adform" action="/" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <label>Emp ID :</label>
        <input id="id" name="empid" placeholder="" type="text">
        <br>
        <br>

        <label>Full Name :</label>
        <input id="name" name="FName" placeholder="Enter your full name" type="text">
        <br>
        <br>

        <label>Designation:</label>
        <input id="name" name="desig" placeholder="Enter your Designation" type="text">
        <br>
        <br>
          
        <label for='DO'>D.O:</label>
        <br>
        <select name="DO" style="WIDTH: 195px; padding: 2px; margin-top: 2px; border: 2px solid #ccc; padding-left: 2px; font-size: 16px; font-family: raleway">
          <option value="">Select a D.O...</option>
          <option value="AHMEDABAD">AHMEDABAD</option>
          <option value="BANGLORE">BANGLORE</option>
          <option value="CHENNAI">CHENNAI</option>
          <option value="COIMBATORE">COIMBATORE</option>
          <option value="DELHI">DELHI</option>
          <option value="ERNAKULAM">ERNAKULAM</option>
          <option value="HYDERABAD">HYDERABAD</option>
          <option value="KARUR">KARUR</option>
          <option value="KOLKATA">KOLKATA</option>
          <option value="MADURAI">MADURAI</option>
          <option value="MUMBAI">MUMBAI</option>
          <option value="SALEM">SALEM</option>
          <option value="TAMBARAM">TAMBARAM</option>
          <option value="TRICHY">TRICHY</option>
          <option value="VIJAYAWADA">VIJAYAWADA</option>
          <option value="VISAKHAPATNAM">VISAKHAPATNAM</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <br>

        <label>BranchCode:</label>
        <input id="name" name="branch" placeholder="Enter your BranchCode" type="number" min="1000" max="9999">
        <br>
        <br>

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Submit ">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!---->
  <div id="div2" style="display:none">
  </div>

  <div id="div3" style="display:none">
    Another Test
  </div>

  <div id="div4" style="display:none">
    Final Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle of the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z-index of content div is wrong

use this styling for content and it will work for you

```
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 37%;
  top: 220px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  z-index: 222222;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

and if you want that your form div should be beside the 
left menu div. than you have to try something else.

[fiddleLink;)](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bbsrw2m0/)

Comment: If I change that z-index then the top navigation bar sub menu will not hover properly

Comment: bro there are lots of styling mistakes. :( why you positioned absolute lots of divs

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/bbsrw2m0/   
that's it bro check this if it's working good

Comment: Danish that is fine. But as said before it will create the issue with top navigation bar drop down.

Comment: oh got it add this   .nav ul ul {   z-index: 999999; } add this